# Error:The name 'you' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have problem with my coding. There is an error which is :

> Error:The name 'you' does not exist in the current context..
>   the ID already exist in the Default.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="you" runat="server">
           <asp:ListItem>zed</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>joey</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>john</asp:ListItem>
```

and Default.aspx.cs

```
string stat = you.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

But when I debug the program, it say that the 'you' doesn't exist in the content. Why does this error occur and how can I fix it?

Comment: may be you have defined another control with same name

Comment: Did you add the control via the IDE's GUI, or type it in?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Both the aspx and the aspx.cs

Answer (score 0):

Where is your closing tag. `</asp:DropDownList>`.Its work perfect.I try it.

Comment: oops. I'm sorry, I forgot to put the </asp:DropDownList> in the question.

Comment: Its ok.There is not any error P:) its run perfect.I try it.May be your `control` and `pagebehind` file is different see carefully.